# Multiple expansion file

Tags: android, google-play, apk-expansion-files

Is it possible to support multiple expansion files for an android application with google play? Now I'm using my own server to download expansion files, but it takes so much interaction with the user (like permissions, external apk install etc...)

I want to download each minigames individually (50-300mb each).

I've checked [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files), but I haven't found there what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not supported by Google Play, unless you count "[Google Play Instant](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/) apps".

However, at Google I/O this year, Google Play demonstrated the [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/) which lets your app be broken into smaller parts which are delivered separately.

Doing this for features is currently only in beta, but you can [sign up to show interest in the Beta here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdjGJg_wLO7GwiMaP23ZI8-E1GHktAzN6rdaGZTCjd1h24axw/viewform).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for! :)

Comment: But: Android App Bundles do not support APK expansion files. However, Google Play still requires that app downloads be 100MB or less. So, for example, when first installing your app, the total size of your base APK and its configuration APKs must equal 100 MB or less. Similarly, the total size of any dynamic feature APK and its configuration APKs must be 100 MB or less. After uploading your app bundle, the Play Console warns you if your app bundle results in APKs that violate this restriction.  

And I have to support bigger files too. :(

Comment: I don't think the plans are finalized, that's why it is in Beta. But I'd imagine they'd value feedback on size restrictions and potential design. I doubt they'd want any feature to be bigger than 100Mb, but if you could potentially split games in half it might be useful.